# Number pipes in Angular2 not working as I would expect

Tags: angular, numbers

```
platform-browser.umd.js:962 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: 2 is not a valid digit info for number pipes
```

Is what I get from writing this in my template:

```
<li>Percentage satisfied: {{selectedCountry.averageSatisfaction | number:2}}</li>
```

My intention is to produce a decimal number with only two decimals. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong? Here is the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: What about `|number:'2'`?

Comment: I can try. When talking numbers must be taking a string (lol)

Comment: This parameter is a string an it needs to match https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a6ad61d83e2c423bd36cdda145fd29f72974535c/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L17 (`{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}`)

Comment: Sorry, it does not seem to do any difference. I cannot check the template directly as it has been converted in the build process. But I will try to check the TypeScript in the component.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-class.html).

The formatting is passed as a parameter to the pipe like this:

```
number:'{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}'
```

Using this with your needs:

```js
number:'1.2-2'
```

This will give you a string with minimum 1 digit before decimal point and exactly 2 after decimal point.

---

Example usage from the docs:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'number-example',
  pipes: [DecimalPipe],
  template: `<div>
    <p>e (no formatting): {{e}}</p>
    <p>e (3.1-5): {{e | number:'3.1-5'}}</p>
    <p>pi (no formatting): {{pi}}</p>
    <p>pi (3.5-5): {{pi | number:'3.5-5'}}</p>
  </div>`
})
export class NumberPipeExample {
  pi: number = 3.141;
  e: number = 2.718281828459045;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ tradePrice }}             // output 2345.78543566   
{{ tradePrice | number : '.1-3' }}   // output 2345.785
```

These values come from the API. Equivalent in Java

```
tradePrice.toFixed(3)  // output 2345.785
```