# Angular 2 - Only Allow 2 Decimal Places For Amounts

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

Im new to Angular 2 and i wa wondering if there is a way to restict and amount field to only allow 2 decimal places.

I have tried the below as i have read a few places it should work but i cant seem get it to.

```
<input id="amountfield" ng-model="vm.transferdetails.Amount" ng-model-options="{ updateOn:'blur' }" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01">
```

If i have to use a directive, what do i need and also can it be formatted with , (commas) for thousands (e.g. 100,000,000.00) when you tab out the field.  Only really intrested in this though if i have to use a directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the input I think will help you.  It was answered in a different post:

[Number pipes in Angular2 not working as I would expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653308/number-pipes-in-angular2-not-working-as-i-would-expect)